# MSSQL corellated subquery

Tags: sql-server, correlated-subquery

How can I transform this code where I used a cursor into a single select statement?

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem1]
    @patientApptID int,
    @iwcID int OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ItemComboWarningid int;

DECLARE warning_cursor CURSOR FOR   
                SELECT distinct [ItemComboWarningID]
                FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw] 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON [icw].[ID]=[icwi].[ItemComboWarningID] 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] on [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID  
                WHERE [pa].[id]=@patientApptID 

OPEN warning_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM warning_cursor   
INTO @ItemComboWarningid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

  BEGIN

 (SELECT [icwi].[itemid]
  FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON [icw].[ID]=[icwi].[ItemComboWarningID]  
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] on [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
    WHERE  [pa].[id]=@patientApptID
    AND [icwi].[ItemComboWarningid]=@ItemComboWarningid) 
    EXCEPT 
    (SELECT DISTINCT [pi].[itemID] 
     FROM [dbo].[PatientItem][pi]  
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON  [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
     WHERE  [pa].[id]=@patientApptID) 

  UNION
( SELECT DISTINCT [pi].[itemID] 
  FROM [dbo].[PatientItem][pi]  
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON  [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
        WHERE  [pa].[id]=@patientApptID) 
        EXCEPT
        (SELECT [icwi].[itemid]
        FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw] 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON [icw].[ID]=[icwi].[ItemComboWarningID]  
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] ON [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
        WHERE  [pa].[id]=@patientApptID
        AND [icwi].[ItemComboWarningid]=@ItemComboWarningid) 

 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
 BEGIN 
    SET @iwcID =  @ItemComboWarningid; 
 END

 FETCH NEXT FROM warning_cursor INTO @ItemComboWarningid
 END
 CLOSE warning_cursor;  
 DEALLOCATE warning_cursor;
 RETURN @iwcID
```

What I tried is

```
Select [icw].[id], [icw].[Message]
FROM  [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  Select * from (SELECT [icwi].[itemid]
                    FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw2] 
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON [icw2].[ID]=[icwi].[ItemComboWarningID]  
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] on [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                    WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182
                    AND [icwi].[ItemComboWarningid]=[icw].[id] 
                    EXCEPT 
                    (SELECT DISTINCT [pi].[itemID] 
                    FROM [dbo].[PatientItem][pi]  
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi2] ON  [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi2].[itemID] 
                    WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182) 

                  UNION
                ( SELECT DISTINCT [pi].[itemID] 
                  FROM [dbo].[PatientItem][pi]  
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi3] ON  [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi3].[itemID] 
                        WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182) 
                        EXCEPT
                        (SELECT [icwi4].[itemid]
                        FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw4] 
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi4] ON [icw4].[ID]=[icwi4].[ItemComboWarningID]  
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] ON [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi4].[itemID] 
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                        WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182
                        AND [icwi4].[ItemComboWarningid]=[icw].[id])))
```

But I get this error "Expecting AS, ID or Quoted_ID".

The main idea is that I want to check every [icw].[id] and if this query returns no rows

```
SELECT [icwi].[itemid]
                      FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw2] 
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi] ON [icw2].[ID]=[icwi].[ItemComboWarningID]  
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] on [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi].[itemID] 
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                        WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182
                        AND [icwi].[ItemComboWarningid]=**[icw].[id]** 
                        EXCEPT 
                        (SELECT DISTINCT [pi].[itemID] 
                         FROM [dbo].[PatientItem][pi]  
                         INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                         INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi2] ON  [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi2].[itemID] 
                         WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182) 

                      UNION
                    ( SELECT DISTINCT [pi].[itemID] 
                      FROM [dbo].[PatientItem][pi]  
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi3] ON  [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi3].[itemID] 
                            WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182) 
                            EXCEPT
                            (SELECT [icwi4].[itemid]
                            FROM [dbo].[ItemComboWarning] [icw4] 
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemComboWarningItem][icwi4] ON [icw4].[ID]=[icwi4].[ItemComboWarningID]  
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientItem][pi] ON [pi].[ItemID]=[icwi4].[itemID] 
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[PatientAppointment][pa] ON [pa].[ID]=[pi].PatientAppointmentID 
                            WHERE  [pa].[id]=3712182
                            AND [icwi4].[ItemComboWarningid]=**[icw].[id]**)
```

then I want to display that id. But I need to make the linking with the **[icw].[id]** from the outer table. How can it be done? thanks!

Comment: Is your original query working at all? Look for `EXCEPTs` they use the same aliases as the main query. You do not have to use brackets for Aliases too.

Comment: Yes, my original stored procedure is working, but I would like to make it a SELECT because of performances issues

Comment: You should really clean your queries first. It looks like your first sub-query should not return any results.

Comment: Have you tried using a CTE (Common Table Expression)?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Basically, the CTE query results are available to the following queries so you can probably use that technique instead of a cursor.